# Copula density bounds

Tags: density-function, copula

I was wondering if someone can help me with a problem I encountered in my work. I need a bivariate copula density that meets two constraints at the bounds, and I have difficulties in finding one that satisfies both. 
More exactly, if I have a copula density $c(u,v)$ I need that these two contraints are satisfied:

1. $\lim\limits _{u\downarrow0}c(1-u,1-v)=a$, where $a$ is finite and $a>0$
2. $\lim\limits _{u\downarrow0}\frac{c(u,v)}{v^k}=b$, where $b$ is finite and $b>0$

I have found copulas that pass point 1 above (i.e. Frank copula, FGM copula), but none that satisfies point 2...Does someone know such a copula density? Or maybe I can construct a copula knowing these two constraints?...